# Connecting a View in connectOutlet with Ember RC1

Tags: ember.js

From this [EDIT] [ToDo's sample][1](https://github.com/tomdale/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/dependency-examples/emberjs_require/js), [/EDIT] I can connect a View via the connectOutlet. Is there an updated example for this using RC1?

```
index: Ember.Route.extend({
  route: '/',
  connectOutlets: function( router ) {

    var controller = router.get( 'applicationController' );
    var context = controller.namespace.entriesController;
    context.set( 'filterBy', '' );

    // This require was left here exclusively for design purposes
    // Loads decoupled controller/view based on current route
    require([ 'app/controllers/todos', 'app/views/items' ],
      function( TodosController, ItemsView ) {
        controller.connectOutlet({
          viewClass: ItemsView,
          controller: TodosController.create(),
          context: context
        });
      }
    );

  }
}),
```

Comment: This seems outdated. Check the [Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the [example](https://github.com/tomdale/todomvc/blob/629cbf72e4c5c99d349f6022289a1318a9e4f4c8/architecture-examples/emberjs/js/router.js) you are linking should work. As you might know the Router API has changed and **the code based on pre4 should still work**. I am not aware of the requirements for the Todos App, so i cannot 100% tell, if it still works:

```
Todos.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('todos', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('active');
    this.route('completed');
  });
});

Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Todos.Todo.find();
  }
});

Todos.TodosIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    var todos = Todos.Todo.find();
    this.controllerFor('todos').set('filteredTodos', todos);
  }
});
```

Here a little **summary of the changes** to the old router API:

- You don't extend the Ember.Router Class anymore.
- The URL Mappings don't reside in the Routes anymore. This is done via Todos.Router.map.
- There is no connectOutlets event anymore in your routes. Instead there are 3 events you can implement: model(), setupController() & renderTemplate().

A little explanation on the hooks:

- **model()**: Is called once when your route is entered via URL. This should return your model, which should become the content of your controller.
- **setupController()**: Here you can get your controller and set its content how you may like. The default implementation sets the controller, that is name matching your route to the result of model().
- **renderTemplate()**: Inside this hook you should use the new render method of routes to do the rendering. The [render](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render) method is somehow the method that matches the old connectOutlets the most. There is also default implementation. Therefore it is also not implemented in the pre4 version of todomvc.

As Milkyway stated, you realy have to read the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/), but i hope this gets you started a little bit better.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer. That sample is in fact outdated (0.9.8.1). The code I have is using the same version and pattern, in particular about the part of assigning  ItemsView to viewClass inside connectOutlets. I've read the guides and there is no mention for an equivalent function. This ToDo sample is using viewContainer which contains a View, which identify templates via the template property in Views. Is there an equivalent way to use something to connect to a viewContainer from inside a Route, similar to what connectOutlets did?

Comment: Have you even looked at the links provided? It is clearly using the new router api. As i said there is no perfect equivalent. If you would look into the doc of the render method of the Route, you would see that the interface is very close to the old connectOutlet of controller.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to refer to the [ToDo's sample](https://github.com/tomdale/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/dependency-examples/emberjs_require/js) that uses requirejs. This ToDo sample is still outdated to 0.9.8.1.  Yes, I've read all Ember guides and links but they don't mention the equivalent to setting a view (viewClass: ItemsView,) inside connectOulet. THanks in advance,

Comment: So your question is actually about requirejs? You asked about Ember. If you are willing to learn the TodoMVC, i suggest looking at the Github Repo of tomdale, who is an Ember Core Team Member.

Comment: And one more hint: There is no connectOutlet anymore. You have to learn the new Router API.

Comment: My question is not about requirejs. The version of the ToDo sample that I'm referring to, just happens to use it. I'm aware there is no connectOutlet anymore, that's precisely my question: what is the equivalent of the old way of setting a viewClass inside a connectOutlet, as RC1 doesn't not include that any longer. Thanks for reading anyway.

Comment: Sorry, but i do not understand why you are not happy with my answers. You have to migrate to the new Router API. I showed you some hints on how to do it. The Version of TodoMVC i linked uses the new router API. What else do you want? I even explained with which concepts the connectOutlets Router event and connectOutlets method of controllers have been replaced. Good luck on getting your problem solved though.